# Hibernate Search: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unknown Analyzer definition: stem_analyzer_definition

Tags: hibernate-search

this is the code I used to build the Lucene Query where I got the Exception mentioned in the Question

```
QueryBuilder builder= fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
.forEntity(Demo.class).overridesForField("level", "stem_analyzer_definition")
.get();
```

Here's the stack trace

```
org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unknown Analyzer definition: stem_analyzer_definition
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.ImmutableSearchFactory.getAnalyzer(ImmutableSearchFactory.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedQueryContextBuilder$HSearchEntityContext.overridesForField(ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.java:98)
    at com.test1.MDTTest.searchP1Hierarchy(MDTTest.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Is this because of a missing jar

Here's a list of the jar's I've included

hibernate-search-engine-4.5.1.Final.jar
hibernate-search-orm-4.5.1.Final.jar
lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
solr-core-3.6.2.jar
solr-analysis-extras-3.6.2.jar
solr-solrj-3.6.2.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-search-analyzers-4.5.1.Final.jar
lucene-analyzers-3.6.2.jar

Comment: Have you defined an analyzer with the name `stem_analyzer_definition` (such as with an `@AnalyzerDef`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you donot define your special analyzer
so no analyzer error came out,
for test, you just to remove this line:
.overridesForField("level", "stem_analyzer_definition")